# Excel strip the bracket and display its value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am new to excel, I need to remove the M from the string and if the value is in bracket, set it as negative, else set it as positive. But I only managed to do it for positive, how can I write a function that fulfills the mentioned condition?

```
If G1 value is (100M) then show -100

If G1 value is 100M then show 100

=LEFT(G1,LEN(G1)-1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are quite a few ways to doing this but there are the basic steps.

- First you need to check your string for the letter `M` with `=search("What",Where)`. This returns the location of the character if it exists and `#VALUE` if not.
- Next we need to evaluate if the `M` was found in our search, this can be done with `=IFERROR(value)` where it will return `true` if the character is **not** found.
- Lastly we need to wrap it all in a `=IF(value, true, false)` statement. I'm using `=VALUE(string)` to convert the value from a string to a number

`=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("M",A2)),-VALUE(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1)),VALUE(A2))`

The drawback with an approach is it does not check that `M` is the last letter in the string, so it would fail with something like `100M100`, this could be easily tested for and corrected by checking for the Position of M with `=SEARCH()` and only returning `=SEARCH()-1` characters with `=LEFT(A1,SEARCH()-1)`

Like:
`=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("M",A1)),-VALUE(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("M",A1)-1)),VALUE(A1))`

If A1 was `100M100` then it would return `-100`

### UPDATE:

I originally misread the question missing the parenthesis. both Abe Gold and Tom Sharpe had correctly done this so I will update my fix my mistake. In this case, assumed that and M was significant to the sign of the result and the parenthesis were redundant. So to correct my answer I would do the following

`=if(IFERROR(search(")",G1)),-VALUE(right(left(G1,search(")",G1)-2),SEARCH(")",G1)-3)),value(LEFT(G1, LEN(G1)-1)))`

Comment: @AbeGold and @PeterSmith did a better job at reading the question then I. but I have fixed it so that it check for the final `)` to select the correct sign.

Answer (score 1):

```
=VALUE(IF(LEFT(G1,1)="(",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(G1,LEN(G1)-2),"(","-"),LEFT(G1,LEN(G1)-1)))
```

Comment: Did you test this? 100M results in 100

Comment: Correct. That's what the question stated the result should be.

Comment: Nope, he said 100M should results in -100, also your solution is incorrect if the value is 100, it returns 10

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(LEFT(G1)="(",-MID(G1,2,LEN(G1)-3),--LEFT(G1,LEN(G1)-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is nicer i think

```
 =VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(G1,"M",""),")",""),"(","-"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of all the conditions, but for the following

- G1 might be numbers with or without the M and the `(...)`
- You always want to return the number if present.

If that is the case, then simply:

```
=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(G1,"M",""))
```

You have not indicated what you would want for a return should the value in G1 be non-numeric.  Just wrap the above in an `IFERROR` function to allow for that.